# Android onLocationChanged

Tags: android, delay, locationmanager

Usually how much time has passed from begin of moving to first onLocationChanged event?
How much are delay time if it is exist, or immediately realize the GPS the begin of moving?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that even the first time you get a locate, onLocationChanged will be called.

In terms of when they are getting called, I do not think there is any sort of polling involved in the default behavior (so there is no specified delay time), but you are able to change it yourself if you plan to do things whenever there is a change in location: https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/get-notified-when-location-changes

Answer (score 0):

i'm just sitting on my laptop with gps enabled on my phone and onlocationchanged is polling non stop. The phone location is not accurate within 40 meters, and onlocationchanged() is giving me a latitude and longitude for 15+ decimal places, which is about 1 angstorm.